# Эффект при hover налезает на другие блоки

Tags: html, css, hover

Нужно что бы эффект при hover появлялся снизу только зелёного квадрата, не появляясь при этом на других блоках. 
И ещё, если мы наводим курсор на место где скрыт блок появляющийся при hover, он начинает дёргаться и вообще ведёт себя странно.

Не могу понять что и как исправить. Помогите плз.

```css
.wrapper {
  border:1px solid red;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ff6600;
}
.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:green;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
 }
.block:hover .block__hover{
  bottom:0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.block__hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: bottom 0.5s;
}

.block2{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block__hover"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.wrapper {
  border:1px solid red;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ff6600;
  position:relative;
  z-index:5;
}
.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:green;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
 }
.block:hover .block__hover{
  bottom:0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.block__hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -50%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: bottom 5.5s;
}

.block2{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:red;
  margin: 0 auto;
   z-index: 3;
   position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block__hover"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Так?

Comment: Да, почти. Но нужно что бы эффект hover не проявлялся на wrapper. Попробовал тоже через z-index, но всё равно налазит на wrapper(

Comment: @Григорий готово я только чуть замедлил для наглядности

Comment: похоже. Но у меня основная загвостка это что бы блок постепенно проявлялся снизу, а сейчас он резко появляется снизу и плавно уходит вверх. 
Вот для наглядности скрин. http://prntscr.com/jsv14d